# Source Control and deployment for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Has anybody come up with a good solution to source control and deploy code to AWS Lambda? I really hate that I have to zip the files all the time and upload them. Is there a better way to do this perhaps a service that pushes code based on changes to Lambda?

Comment: You could use something like Code Ship to deploy it to S3 when you make a push to GitHub, then have lambda read from the S3 Bucket.

Comment: You can checkout out https://github.com/garnaat/kappa. I wrote it so I'm biased but I think it provides a decent deploy tool for Lambda.

Comment: What language(s) are you using?

Comment: node.js, are there any other tools that are not CLI?

Comment: I know the question was about synchronizing source control versions with the published Lambda, but [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html) may still be useful for people who may arrive at this question. It is more about pinning executable Lambda versions, but still relevant. If you have a method for auto-deploying your source control tags to the target lambda, you could pin them with this.

Answer (score 10):

You can try [Serverless Framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) for this. Current beta looks very promising.

Serverless Framework allow you to build entire application without any servers. It combines AWS API Gateway with AWS Lambda functions and supports auto-deployment.

Beta v1 release supports NodeJS only, but they plan to support for all languages.

Project Docs: http://docs.serverless.com/v0.5.0/docs

Comment: I tried out serverless and despite the ten thousand stars on github, I had to fight with it a lot, and it still left junk hanging around in my AWS account that was hard to clean up manually.  Definitely promising, but not there yet.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your/workspace

#zips up the new code
zip -FSr yourzipfile.zip . -x *.git* *bin/\* *.zip

#Updates function code of lambda and pushes new zip file to s3bucket for cloudformation lambda:codeuri source
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name  arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:YOURID:function:YOURFUNCTIONNAME --zip-file fileb://yourzipfile.zip
aws s3 cp yourzipfile.zip s3://yourbucketname/yourzipfile.zip
```

Depends on aws-cli install and aws profile setup

```
aws --profile yourProfileName configure
```

And my rant: I wish cloudformation lambda:codeuri would accept any url not just s3://bucketname/filename... so I could point it straight to github.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, you can utilize AWS Toolkit for Eclipse: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/ug/tke_setup.html). This allows you to use any source control you want and deploy your code to AWS with two clicks.

Comment: any source control you want as long as your lambda is written in java...