# Alternate options to manage the configurations for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

At the moment I am building various REST API's using AWS API Gateway, which is going great, but I am managing all these API's just through the WEB UI (Usual AWS Console ).

Is there a way, I can store all my API config in a source control ? So that I can keep track of the versions ? I don't want to just depend on API Gateway alone for these configurations, it will be great to have these API specifications in a source control.

Also I understand that API gateway supports swagger, that way I can store the swagger API specification somewhere. BUT I guess swagger won't cover all aspects of an API, For eg: if I am using mappings templates in API Gateway for talking to DynamoDB, how can I manage the mapping templates ?

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Swagger is the native solution. Mapping templates would be a little funky of course but it's still all in one file. Open source frameworks like serverless are also great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684146/source-control-and-deployment-for-aws-lambda) has been asked some time ago and I dont have a better answer

Hopefully, meanwhile, the [serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) has improved a lot. It can support `nodejs` and `python2.7` code and `java` should come.

serverless also supports [Templates & Variables](http://docs.serverless.com/docs/templates-variables) so so you can manage your dynamo resource from a Json or yaml file

Note: the [aws-api-gateway](/questions/tagged/aws-api-gateway) already exists so feel free to use